# Every time I use my web app, I just create my data table again. how to fix this trouble?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am learning developing web app on google app engine, and I encounter a trouble.
I have some default users in my app and I write a function createDefaultUsers to create a User table using a list of their information in my python file. I hope to create this User table just once and every time I use my app, the data just there. But you know, the createDefaultUsers function is in my python file, so, very time I use my app, I just create this User table again and again. OGM~How can I fix this problem?

another question:
How can I clear my local datastore? It may help me debug my app, you know, sometime I just want to start again.

--------------Update----------------

For example, here is some default users :

```
defaultUsers = [
('qingWANG','wang123456','wangqing@saad.com','teacher'),
('stevenYANG','123456','yifan@gmail.com','student'),
('jingZHU','zhu123456','zhujing@example.com','student'),
('conghuiHE','he123456','conghui@where.com','student'),
('lianDUAN','duan123456','duanlian@what.com','student'),
('xinHAO','hao123456','haoxin@example.com','student')]
```

and here is my function which create Users:

```
def createDefaultUsers():
"""
create default user table
"""
for user in defaultUsers:
    users = Users(name = user[0], password = user[1],
                  email = user[2], role = user[3])
    users.put()
```

In my first think, I put createDefaultUsers here:

```
def main():
    createDefaultUsers()
    run_wsgi_app(app)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

It is fine in my local testing. But when I deploy this, It doesn't work (seems no Users created). where am I wrong?

Comment: you need to show your code to get proper help. are you having issues in the local SDK or in production. (there are no tables in GAE)

Comment: @aschmid00 I add some code, and the question may change a little. the code I post works locally but can't work when I deploy it.

Comment: The way your code is pasted, the contents of your function aren't properly indented. If this is how it actually is, then it will be running every time your file is imported

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily modify the function to check to see if there are any existing users and if there are, don't create them:

```
def createDefaultUsers():
    """
    create default user table
    """
    user_count = Users.all().count(1)
    if user_count == 0:
        for user in defaultUsers:
            new_user = Users(name = user[0], password = user[1],
                  email = user[2], role = user[3])
            new_user.put()
```

Do note that the `count()` query operation is expensive because it actually retrieves all of the entities from the datastore in order to count them, so it is to be avoided in common practice, but by specifying a limit of 0, we can make it simple and quick in this case.

You can empty out your development datastore by passing the command line argument `--clear-datastore` to the development server. Here are all of `dev_appserver.py` [command line arugments](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver#Command_Line_Arguments)

Comment: Thank you. But I can't find dev_appserver.py in my project and I can't find index.yaml too. Why? I'm in win7.

Comment: Are you using the AppEngine App Launcher to start your application?

Comment: Yes, I user Launcher to start app and use pycharm as my IDE.

Comment: It's probably installed in c:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine. Alternatively, you can set command line options inside the App Launcher. From the Edit menu, select Application Settings. There's a box labeled 'Extra Command Line Flags'. You can put `--clear-datastore` in there. Just don't forget to remove it when you *don't* want to clear the datastore.

Comment: Thanks. I found dev_appserver.py, but I'm curious that why I don't have a index.yaml file in my project? It is generate automatically ,isn't it?  may it affect my deploymen ?

Comment: If your application performs any queries, the development server should automatically generate an index.yaml file. You must actually use the application in such a way that all of the queries are actually executed, though.

Comment: I found not all the queries make server generate index.yaml content. is this right?